# How does an Xcode Bot choose the certificate used to sign an .ipa if everything is set to "Automatic"?

Tags: xcode, ios-provisioning, xcode-bots

As per [this Apple article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1814/_index.html), I have set up my project to automatically code sign.

A Bot set to run a scheme using the "Release" configuration builds an archive which uploads to TestFlight fine (via [pilot](https://github.com/fastlane/pilot).)

A Bot set to run a scheme using the "Debug" configuration builds, but fails to upload to TestFlight because of a certificate error. Inspecting the .ipa, its `embedded.mobileprovision` contains a development certificate.

Why? What makes Xcode decide to use a Development certificate for Debug builds and a Distribution certificate for Release builds?

Comment: It does so with the team you select for the project I think.

Comment: The linked article says "Set the Code Signing Identity build setting: Set to iOS Developer for all build configurations in iOS targets.", which is what we have—even for `Release`. Yet the release Bot still builds an .ipa with the distribution cert.

Answer (score 0):

The debug builds use the iOS Team Provisioning Profiles.  If you set the team on the Xcode portion of the Server app, it automatically downloads all the profiles to the right directory in your system for the bot to locate them.  Otherwise you have to copy them manually to the /library/developer/xcodeserver/provisioning profile directory.

[image]

Comment: This is all true and it works for my Release builds. But for any other configuration, it picks the Development cert and not a Distribution cert. I want the bot to sign with a Distribution cert after building with a configuration that's not Release.

Comment: Have you tried to specific that certificate in the build settings for the debug target?

Comment: Yes, and doing so breaks automatic provisioning totally. I want to avoid manually copying profiles around—they change every time you plug a new test device into a developer's machine.

Comment: My bot was having issues building the debug version. My error was 
No matching codesigning identity found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) matching XXXX” were found. I realized that  for "Automatic" it was using the "iOS Team Provisioning Profile:xxxxxxx"

Comment: TestFlight I believe does not allow debug version to be uploaded

Comment: I created a new configuration ("Beta") cloned from Release, and building that configuration got me the same result as trying to upload the Debug build—it was signed with the development profile.